# Postgresql как передать в одну переменную несколько параметров

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Всем привет, есть такой запрос для поиска:

```
 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
    "with koliz as (select distinct on(osdch_t,osdch_r,osdch_c,osdk_t,osdk_r,osdk_c " +
        ",kiz) osdch_t, osdch_r, osdch_c, osdk_t, osdk_r, osdk_c, kiz, svi, kol, koliz " +
    "from clippersql.vp44150sql " +
    "where osdch_c||osdch_r like'" + osdch + "%'"   +
            "and osdk_c||osdk_r like '" + osdk + "%'" +
            "and kiz like '" + kiz + "%'" +
            "and svi <= '" + svi + "%' " +
    "order by osdch_t,osdch_r,osdch_c,osdk_t,osdk_r,osdk_c,kiz,svi desc " +
    "limit " + 100 + " offset " + count + ")
```

Задача состоит в том что бы в `input` можно было передавать не один параметр для `kiz`, а несколько, можно ли это как-то реализовать? Слышал про такую конструкцию как: `where kiz in ('Value1','Value2'...)`, но не знаю как его применить можно к моему запросу.

Comment: Вы уже пишите sql кодом... Неужели не подумали написать сервис для генерации команды IN? делаете обычную функцию с вариадиком, на входе множество, на выходе строка. ИМХО, самый примитивный способ, и не нарушит вашу самодельную "идилию" в виде sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java-код для SQL-кода предложенного @Mike

```
List<String> someKizList = ...

String kizValues = "(" + String.join("), (", someKizList) + ")";

String query = "with koliz as (select distinct on(osdch_t, osdch_r, osdch_c,"
             + "osdk_t, osdk_r, osdk_c, kiz) osdch_t, osdch_r, osdch_c, osdk_t, "
             + "osdk_r, osdk_c, kiz, svi, kol, koliz from clippersql.vp44150sql, "
             + "(values " + kizValues + ") X(skiz)"
             + "where osdch_c || osdch_r like'?%' and osdk_c||osdk_r like '?%'"
             + "and kiz like X.skiz||'%' and svi <= '?%' order by osdch_t, osdch_r, "
             + "osdch_c, osdk_t, osdk_r, osdk_c, kiz, svi desc "
             + "limit " + 100 + " offset " + count + ")";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)
preparedStatement.setString(1, osdch);
preparedStatement.setString(2, osdk);
preparedStatement.setString(3, svi);
```

Но всё решение в целом выглядит как мертворожденное. Чую, там всё в корне переписывать надо.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте нужные значения в саму выборку, в таком виде:

```
from clippersql.vp44150sql, (values('aaa'),('bbb')) X(skiz)
```

Значения перечисляются через запятую, каждое в отдельных круглых скобках.
После этого у вас в выборке доступна "таблица" X с полем skiz и вам остается переписать like в виде:

```
and kiz like X.skiz||'%'
```

Comment: я так понимаю мне  сюда `values('aaa'),('bbb')` задавать мои `kiz` в ручную нужно?

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Да, вместо aaa и bbb. Но вы же все равно не используете подготавливаемые выражения и плейсхолдеры, а подставляете значения прямо в запрос (чего делать вообще то нельзя, ибо sql-инъекции и прочие проблемы). Но если продолжаете работать так же, то собираете строку чем то вроде joining  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577565/5669174) с разделителем `'),('` и  добавляете в начале и конце недостающие скобки и кавычки

Comment: просто у меня их больше трёх тысяч уникальных `kiz`, это же явно не правильно в ручную их задавать, значит нужно искать другой подход

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Программно, это не в ручную. И вы в вопросе написали "_что бы в input можно было передавать не один параметр для kiz, а несколько_" и слова "тысяч" там не было. У вас человек в input введет несколько тысяч значений и будет по ним всем искать ? Ну если так, то вы можете создать отдельную таблицу в БД и записать все эти значения туда и в запросе вместо слова values использовать реальную таблицу

Comment: @СергейНиконенко И вы же зами хотели использовать `IN('aaa','bbb')` т.е. перечислить в IN несколько тысяч вы были готовы, а перечислить в values нет ?

Comment: нет, я наверное просто не правильно выразился, вот смотрите есть инпут, с запросом выше, оно работает так, человек вводит "ИК62", идет поиск всех записей с этим значением, а нужно сделать что бы пользователь мог указать два `kiz`, или три, но эти два-три могут быть любыми из  тех трех тысяч уникальных, примерно так)

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Ну это вы у себя в java решите как это лучше реализовать, несколько полей input сделать и добавлять их по мере ввода или попросить человека в одно поле вводить через запятую. Как бы человек не ввел эти значения вам надо сформировать из них вот ту строку для values